# Disable a table row if it's attribute is display:none;?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table and i want my rows that have the "display:none;" attribute to be disabled so their values don't get sent to database.

EDIT : I tried this code
`$('form > tr:hidden').prop("disabled",true);  $('form').submit();`

Comment: Please show us some code so we know what you've tried.

Comment: You need to set `disabled` on your input elements not the tr, try changing your selector to : `$('form > tr:hidden input').prop("disabled",true)`

Comment: I have <select> inside my rows, does this work? or do i change input to select

Comment: you can change it or use find to group elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the html this is based on, I'm going to guess that the issue is with your selector.  As DaniP said, the input elements need to be disabled, not the row.

The other issue I see is the use of the greater than symbol, as in

```
form > tr
```

The greater than symbol restricts your selection to only first level descendants.  In other words, `form > tr` expects that you have html code like so, where tr is a child of form:

```
<form>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</form>
```

But, I bet you have a table element in there as well, right?  Like this:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

form > tr would not select the row in this case.  Combining what DaniP said, try this as your selector:

```
$('form tr:hidden input').prop("disabled",true);
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, it was the " > " symbol.. and thanks for everyone else for their effort and sorry for the lack of html i thought it was a simple idea